# Can´t update database with sent value

Tags: php, html, sql

I can not update my database with sent variable "$id_zaznamu". I do not know why. If I use number, for example 5 or 4, it works. With variable "$id_zaznamu" doesn´t. But in the different examples with variabable $id_zaznamu everythning works correctly. In other words exactly the same variable "$id_zaznamu" works correctly in different situations, in this case not. It seems to me as if it is not integer, and it is. For any help I will be very thankful.

PHP:

```
$id_zaznamu=$_GET['id_zaznamu']; //get from different page
$error="";
if(isset($_GET['modify']))
{
    $zadavatel=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['zadavatel']);
    $kontakt=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_GET['kontakt']); $somevalue=$_GET['someid'];

    if(mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE zaznamy SET zadavatel='$zadavatel', kontakt='$kontakt' WHERE id_zaznam='$somevalue'"))
        {
            header("location:vypis.php");
        }else 
        {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
        }

}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="GET" action="upravbyt.php"><br>

    <label>Name: 
    <input type="text" name="zadavatel" class="field col-12" placeholder="Meno zadávateľa"/></label><br><br>
    <label>Contact: 
    <input type="text" name="kontakt" class="field col-12" placeholder="Email"/></label><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="someid" value="<?php $id_zaznamu=$_GET['id_zaznamu'];?>">
    <input type="submit" name="modify" id="submit" class="btn" value="Upraviť"/><br><br>
    </form>
```

Comment: You're not sending `id_zaznamu` in your form

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I have inserted "error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');" and it reports "Undefined index: id_zaznamu in C:\...\upravbyt.php on line 15". But it will show after modify and send a form. Before not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
<input name="id_zaznamu"  value="...">
```